# List Index out of range en Google Colab

Tags: python, redes-neuronales, google-colab

Estoy intentando hacer una clasificación de imágenes mediante entrenamiento no supervisando con CNN y clustering con el algoritmo de keras en python en el notebook de Google Colab.

El problema que tengo, es que a la hora de guardar las imágenes que tengo en Google Drive en una lista en Google Colab me salta el siguiente error:

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Es muy raro, porque en mi máquina en local este error no ocurre.

La linea en concreto donde me marca el error es:

```
dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
```

¿Alguien podria saber porque?

Dejo aqui el codigo completo:

```
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

dirname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'drive\My Drive\Celulas1\Celulas\entrenamiento')
imgpath = dirname + os.sep 

 
images = []
directories = []
dircount = []
prevRoot=''
cant=0
 
print("leyendo imagenes de entrenamiento de: ",imgpath)
 
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(imgpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
            cant=cant+1
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            image = plt.imread(filepath)
            image = image.astype('float32')
            
        
            images.append(image)
  
            b = "Leyendo..." + str(cant)
            print (b, end="\r")
            if prevRoot !=root:
                print(root, cant)
                prevRoot=root
                directories.append(root)
                dircount.append(cant)
                cant=0
dircount.append(cant)
dircount = dircount[1:]
dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
print('Directorios leidos:',len(directories))
print("Imagenes en cada directorio", dircount)
print('suma Total de imagenes en subdirs:',sum(dircount))


dirname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'drive\My Drive\Celulas1\Celulas\test')
imgpath = dirname + os.sep 

 
images2 = []
directories2 = []
dircount2 = []
prevRoot=''
cant=0
 
print("leyendo imagenes de testeo de: ",imgpath)
 
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(imgpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
            cant=cant+1
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            image = plt.imread(filepath)
            image = image.astype('float32')
            
        
            images2.append(image)
  
            b = "Leyendo..." + str(cant)
            print (b, end="\r")
            if prevRoot !=root:
                print(root, cant)
                prevRoot=root
                directories2.append(root)
                dircount2.append(cant)
                cant=0
dircount2.append(cant)
dircount2 = dircount2[1:]
dircount2[0]=dircount2[0]+1
print('Directorios leidos:',len(directories2))
print("Imagenes en cada directorio", dircount2)
print('suma Total de imagenes en subdirs:',sum(dircount2))
```

Dejo aqui el error para que lo veais mas en detalle:

```
leyendo imagenes de entrenamiento de:  /content/drive\My Drive\Celulas1\Celulas\entrenamiento/

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-64895f891c0e> in <module>()
     39 dircount.append(cant)
     40 dircount = dircount[1:]
---> 41 dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
     42 print('Directorios leidos:',len(directories))
     43 print("Imagenes en cada directorio", dircount)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Gracias de antemano!

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema son los directorios vacios.

Cuando el directorio está vacio, `dircount` sale en cero del `for`. Entonces

```
dircount.append(cant)
```

deja `dircount = [0]`, y está otra

```
dircount = dircount[1:]
```

deja `dircout = []`, por lo que

```
dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
```

genera una excepción de indice.

**Solución**

Agregar un condicional:

```
dircount.append(cant)
if len(dircount) > 1:
    dircount = dircount[1:]
    dircount[0] = dircount[0] + 1
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta y perdon por tardar en contestar.

Ya lo arregle, con tu respuesta!